# Missing period for Samsung Galaxy S4 numeric keypad

Tags: html, samsung-mobile, html-input

I have the tag `<input type="number" pattern="[0-9\.]*" />` and trying to get the numeric keypad with an option to enter a period to show once the user selects the field.

The above code works for iPhone 4/5 and Samsung Galaxy S3 but not on the S4. The S4 shows the numeric keypad but does not display the period button. Highly frustrating as it does so in the S3!

Anyone know of a fix for the S4 standard keyboard setup?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that there is a problem with the Samsung S4 keyboard. The only way i have found to avoid the problem is by installing another keyboard...

There are countless threads and reports of this when searching google...

Often it is recommended to use google's keyboard. Personally i prefer SwiftKey

http://www.businessinsider.com/google-keyboard-for-android-2013-6

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.touchtype.swiftkey&hl=no